# String to integer conversion in Java

Tags: java, android

For one of my project I have to convert String to integer.  How to convert `"16:45:20"` string to integer in java. I am using

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(string)
```

It's giving me `NumberFormatException` error. How to solve this

Comment: What do you expect as a result? 16 hours, 45 minutes, 20 seconds, as a seconds value? A date/time integer (seconds since the UNIX epoch)?

Comment: Have you googled on this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you want it to return?  The number of seconds in the timespan?  Or is this a time in 24H format?  What integer do you expect to get from your example input string?  If you just want the numeric characters as an integer, then yeah, you will need to split the string on the colons and then concatenate it and then parse the int.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert to integer because `"16:45:20"` is not valid integer

You may need to split based on `:` delimeter

Then loop over `String[]` and convert each one to corresponding int.

You will get three separate ints 16,45,20

```
String[] tempArr = str.split(":");
int val1 = Integer.valueOf(tempArr[0]);
```

Comment: @Prasad: Added some example code.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. for my project i have give time in a format like 16:45:20. whenevr i tried to parse to int its giving num format error. how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the hour, you can use a code like this:

```java
package stackoverflow.time;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Type the hour and press 'Enter': ");
        String time = s.next();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, formatter);
        System.out.println("The time typed was: " + localTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split string by ":" then append to string

Comment: Even if the : is split, it cant translate to 164512, it is not a recoverable value. Its obvious he is trying to convert time to long to store somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly convert to integer because "16:45:20" is not valid integer

You may need to split.

Try this way:

```
  String str = "16:45:20";

    String[] split = str.split(":");
    System.out.println("Hour :========>"+split[0]);
    System.out.println("Min :========>"+split[1]);
    System.out.println("Sec :========>"+split[2]);

    int hour = Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
    int Min = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
    int Sec = Integer.valueOf(split[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** You need to **split** the `String` using `:` as the **delimiter** before converting it into int.

**Eg:**

```
String s = "16:45:20";
String[] arr = s.split(":");

int x = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
int z = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
```